# Missing manage currency option in set-up

Tags: multi-currency

Missing manage currency option in set-up

I just enabled 
'Allow Support to Activate Multiple Currencies' from company Information

I am using developer ORG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you could request for Multi currency in DEV org because this edition of salesforce is exceptionally used as play ground & you can't expect salesforce will give you additional features on request.

Multi-currency can enable in the org by raising case on support and from Dev Org , this feature is disabled now.

To play around Multicurreny , use sandboxes and production and the process to enable currency is in below URL.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003638

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue recently. Steps to resolve:

- Email developer@salesforce.com with orgId, login granted, support-enabled to make change on Company page
- Wait
- Wait some more
- Wait 25 days (this is how long it took)

Response was:

```
Hello, we have activated multi-currency for this account.
```

Answer (score 0):

Multicurrency will take some time to get activated.

You will need to raise a case with salesforce support explaining why you need this feature .

Once it's approved ,it will be activated and you will see various options to manage currency

Comment: can we raise a case for developer edition ?

Comment: Yes sure .You can raise a case .

Comment: Thanks,  I am not able to raise a case , can you help me how can I raise a case ?

Comment: Use this for logging case http://www.simplysfdc.com/2015/12/how-to-log-case-to-salesforce-support.html?m=1

Comment: I don't think we can raise a case to salesforce with developer org.

Comment: Ah did they stopped supporting dev box?